# OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Tags: networking, python, programming

When doing a network broadcast from Python, I get this: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

My code is as follows:

```
def send(ip, message):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((ip, 4601))
    try:
        sock.sendall(message)
        response = sock.recv(1024)
    finally:
        sock.close()
    if response:
        return response
    else:
        return False
```

I replaced ip with "<broadcast>" and that's when I get the error. My server is listening on port 4601 so I don't understand what's going on. I also replaced it with the actual network broadcast address provided in network-manager and still got nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of broadcast, you should not use TCP rather you should use UDP. Then again you need to use `sendto()`  method instead of `connect()`. `sendto()` is used to send data to a certain address which is the "broadcast" address in our case. So the following should work:

```
import socket
message = "Hello"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.sendto(message, ('<broadcast>', 50000))
```